# Clear an execCommand font size in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, execcommand

Using `document.execCommand('fontsize', false, 5);`, I then want to clear or remove the font size. If I use removeFormat, it will remove any other formatting, so this isn't ideal. If I set fontsize to 2 or 3 it may appear okay, but this is also not ideal. Is there a simple way to clear a font size, without going in there "manually"?